# Correct use of passive causative structures

Tags: semi-modals, causative-have, causative-get

I am asked to write on "things you want to have done".

My interpretation of that question is I have to write on things I want people do for me, not things I wish I had done in the past. Correct ?

Most of the examples I found online presents sentences like this one :

"Thirdly, I should get one of my apartment’s entrance all reconstructed because it is literally falling apart."

> Subject + (modal) + get/have + object + past participle + (by agent).

What I'm wondering is if I am allowed to combine have and get, as in the next sentence :

"Fourthly, in that apartment, the bath tub is also falling apart so **I have to get it replaced.** "

Is **have to** considered as a modal so the sentence is in fact a passive causative or is it incorrect to use have to the way I did ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *have* in *have to X* is not modal - *have* when followed by *to {infinitive}* has a separate meaning distinct from *have {object}*, or *have* when used as an auxillary verb.

You usually don't need a modal like *must*, *should*, *need* - the ones that indicate obligation - because *have to X* itself means *required to do/obligated to do X* - the meaning is "built-in."

A modal with *have to X* can certainly be used if needed, though - one that makes sense is *might*:

> I might have to have it replaced soon.

So, *I have to get it replaced* is correct.  You could also save *I have to have it replaced* and it will mean the same.

Comment: Some older British English speakers treat that *have* as an auxiliary, so they say things like *Have I to sign both forms?*   Most speakers treat it as a lexical verb, though, so they say *Do I have to sign both forms?* (*A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*, p.40.)